# Como sumar valores dentro que se repitan dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, poo

Tengo un objeto con valores repetidos que necesito sumar y generar un único resultado.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import { getData } from "../services/api_aralsoft";
import { getArrObjetc } from "../Functions/functions";

const ListReport = () => {
  let array1 = [];
  let array2 = [];
  let array3 = [];

  const example = async () => {
    const api = await getData();
    const filter = api.filter((el) => {
      const soles = el.soles;
      array1.push(soles);
      const proveedor = el.proveedor;
      array2.push(proveedor);
      const articulo = el.codZona;
      array3.push(articulo);
    });
    return getArrObjetc(array2, array3, array1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    example();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Probando la tabla aqui</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListReport;
```

Este es un ejemplo del objeto que obtengo:

```
0: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 2774.2374}
1: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711}
2: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 272.5424}
3: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711}
4: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1076.4336}
5: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 408.3024}
6: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1150.6704}
```

Lo que necesito es generar un nuevo objeto que sume el total de los valores de todo lo que coincida en filas y columnas.

Quedando algo asi:

```
1: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 3488.65402} //En valores esta la sumatoria de todo lo que tiene la columna 1021 de la fila JABONERIA WILSON S.A
2: {filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 2635.4064} //y aqui en valores esta la sumatoria de todo lo que tiene la columna 1031 de la fila JABONERIA WILSON S.A
```

Comment: es un objeto de objetos o arreglo de objetos?...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev es un arreglo de objetos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hice aquí fue crear un nuevo arreglo, que va a contener los objetos en los que estén guardados los valores, primero recorremos el primer arreglo (donde están tus objetos), y buscamos dentro del segundo arreglo el índice del objeto que tenga la misma fila y la misma columna, si no lo encontramos, pusheamos al arreglo el objeto actual, y si lo encontramos, sumamos el valor del objeto en el que nos encontremos en la iteración

```js
const objArray = [
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 2774.2374},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 272.5424},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1076.4336},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 408.3024},
{filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1150.6704}
]

const resultObjArray = []

objArray.forEach(element => {
    const objectIndex = resultObjArray.findIndex(obj => obj.filas === element.filas && obj.columnas === element.columnas)
  if(objectIndex === -1){
    resultObjArray.push(element)
  } else{
    resultObjArray[objectIndex].valores += element.valores
  }
})

console.log(resultObjArray)
```

Comment: tu solucion me funciono pero el resultado se me duplica, es como si me multiplicara los valores por 2. no entiendo que pasa?

Comment: cómo se duplica? tienes ejemplo? si corres el código funciona

Comment: @Naidamag Sin embargo lo marcaste como aceptada y quitaste del mío :/ hay un error en mi código? también me pregunto lo mismo...

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev gracias por tu ayuda y si cuando probe con tu codigo me percate que ademas de sumar los valores tambien unias en un solo resultado el contenido de filas. Lo que pasa es que aqui solo puse un fragmento de mi objeto cuando lo pruebo con el objeto me doy cuenta que con tu codigo no me funciona.

Comment: @JorgeAlmada Si corro tu codigo funciona, pero cuando pruebo tu funcion en mi proyecto con el objeto completo me doy cuenta la suma de los valores se me duplica, pero es un error que tengo yo en mis funciones, de hecho puse el caso en otra pregunta que tu mismo me respondiste https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/564570/como-evitar-que-se-duplique-el-resultado-de-mi-funcion-en-reactjs/564573#564573

Comment: Ah qué curioso jaja, qué bueno que te funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Si es un arreglo de objetos, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var arr = [
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 2774.2374 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 272.5424 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1021', valores: 220.93711 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1076.4336 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 408.3024 },
  { filas: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', columnas: '1031', valores: 1150.6704 },
];
result = [];

arr.forEach(function (object) {
  if (!this[object.filas] && !this[object.columnas]) {
    this[object.columnas] = { filas: object.filas, columnas: object.columnas, valores: 0 };
    result.push(this[object.columnas]);
  }
  this[object.columnas].valores += object.valores;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```