# Como evitar que se duplique el resultado de mi funcion en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, funciones, depuración

Tengo una funcion que cuando intento ver el resultado por consola me percato que inicialmente tiene 449 registros pero seguidamente me muestra 898 como puedo evitar esto? El total correcto es de 449.

Esta es mi funcion:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { getData } from "../services/api";
import { getArrObjetc } from "../Functions/functions";

const ListReport = () => {
  let array1 = [];
  let array2 = [];
  let array3 = [];

  const example = async () => {
    const api = await getData();
    const filter = api.filter((el) => {
      array1.push(el.soles);
      array2.push(el.proveedor);
      array3.push(el.codZona);
    });
    return getArrObjetc(array2, array3, array1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("aquiii", example());
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Probando la tabla aqui</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListReport;
```

Esta es la funcion getArrObjetc()

```
export const getArrObjetc = (arrProveedor, arrProductos, arrSoles) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i in arrProveedor) {
    arr.push({
      filas: arrProveedor[i],
      columnas: arrProductos[i],
      valores: arrSoles[i],
    });
  }
  return arr;
};
```

Si alguien me puede decir por que me esta pasando eso y como puedo corregirlo.

Esto es lo que veo por consola, primero muestra el array de 449 y seguidamente carga ese otro resultado de 898. El correcto es de 449

```
aquiii Promise[[Prototype]]: Promise
              [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
              [[PromiseResult]]: Array(449)

aquiii Promise[[Prototype]]: Promise
              [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
              [[PromiseResult]]: Array(898)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa tu index.js, probablemente tu  esté wrappeada con <React.Strictmode>, este React.Strictmode hace que el hook useEffect, junto con otras cosas, se corran dos veces, lo que causa que tu función se corra dos veces, esto sólo pasa en el entorno de desarrollo. Puedes probar quitando React.Strictmode, pero recuerda que este Strictmode es el que te avisa en tu consola los errores que puedas llegar a tener en tu proyecto

Comment: eso quiere decir que cuando este en produccion no tendré este problema. Porque necesito seguir trabajando en mi proyecto y para mi es fundamental ver los errores en consola. Entonces no creo conveniente quitar React.Strictmode,